# R: grouping factors everytime n unique levels occur in data

Tags: r, unique, grouping, levels, factors

I want a new grouping every time there's 5 unique levels

Ex. varB is the desired result

```
structure(list(varA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("badger", "cat", "dog", "monkey", 
"turtle"), class = "factor"), varB = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("varA", "varB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

*edit*: some assumptions about the data:

- levels get repeated later in data
- new levels occur later in the data
- there's no fixed ordering in the data

Comment: Is the starting level always going to be the same? (For example, `cat` in this case.)

Comment: @mrdwab I was editing the description before seeing your post. There's no fixed _starting_ level.

Answer (score 4):

Using modulo division on cumsum of "new" values:

```
dat$cu5 <- with(dat, 1+ cumsum( c(0, varA[-length(varA)] != varA[-1])) %/% 5)
```

Adding one is only needed if you want the numbering to start at 1. If you factored it and added labels it would not be needed.

Comment: + 1 great solution! this solved the problem I mentioned in another post!

Comment: ah yeah, that's a good question. What happens when there's not enough unique levels to do the grouping? I'd expect it to just have 1 grouping, but it looks like it groups the reps by 5 instead.

Comment: I guess it doesn't work in that instance. Neither does lselzers' and I don't think @ttmaccer's works in the longer cases either since the `!duplicated(dat$varA)` expression in his first solution returns FALSE forever after the first series and this test case throws an error with his second solution.

Comment: I was rather hoping Jose would allocate the checkmark to a better solution. I don't have any experience with deleting accepted answers.

Comment: @DWin sorry, didn't have a chance to check the thread until now. I removed the "accepted answer" although this is the code I ended using in my script.